# How can i have 2 vertically stacked MUI accordions take up 50% of the parent and internally scroll only their contents?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, frontend

I want to have 2 [React MUI Accordions](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-accordion/) stacked vertically in a div. When a singular one of these accordions is expanded, it takes up the available room, but leaves the other's label untouched (it just pushes it to the edge if necessary). If both are expanded, they should both take up a maximum of 50% of the parent div's height. Now heres the tricky part: When the accordions are expanded and their content overflows the accordion, i want the content to be internally scrollable in *each* accordion, but *only* the content. I want the accordion titles (AccordionSummary component) to stay put when content scrolling occurs.

Here is a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/red-wave-rdm2nb?file=/src/App.js) i made which shows behavior similar to that which i described above. However, in this one the accordion title scrolls with the content, which is not what i want. The top accordion also only goes down 50% of the way when the second one is closed, instead of the full length of the available space, pushing the accordion 2 label down.

Edit: I've been continuing attempts to solve the problem and there seems to be something particular about how the mui AccordionDetails is rendered that doesnt trigger overflow properly. A setup with display: flex on the container, flex 0 1 auto on the title container, flex 1, overflow: 'auto', and minHeight: 0 seems to work when not using the accordion components.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your accordion titles `sticky` by adding this style to both of them:

```
<AccordionSummary
  style={{ position: "sticky", top: 0, backgroundColor: "white" }}
>
```

[This sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-archimedes-iyhn9f?file=/src/App.js) is the updated version of yours along with this update.

Comment: This works in that the label is stopped from scrolling, but the scroll bar goes up to the edge of the label. Ideally there would be a solution which only has the content scrolling, and not the AccordionSummary